# How do I cluster strings based on a relation between two strings?

Tags: data-mining

*If you don't know WEKA, you can try a theoretical answer. I don't need literal code/examples...*

I have a huge data set of strings in which I want to cluster the strings to find the most related ones, these could as well be seen as duplicate. I already have a set of couples of string for which I know that they are duplicate to each other, so, now I want to do some data mining on those two sets.

The result I'm looking for is a system that would return me the possible most relevant couples of strings for which we don't know yet that they are duplicates, I believe that I need clustering for this, which type?

Note that I want to base myself on **word occurrence comparison**, not on interpretation or meaning.

---

Here is an example of two string of which we know they are duplicate (in our vision on them):

- The weather is really cold and it is raining.
- It is raining and the weather is really cold.

Now, the following strings also exist (most to least relevant, ignoring stop words):

- Is the weather really that cold today?
- Rainy days are awful.
- I see the sunshine outside.

The software would return the following two strings as most relevant, which aren't known to be duplicate:

- The weather is really cold and it is raining.
- Is the weather really that cold today?

Then, I would mark that as duplicate or not duplicate and it would present me with another couple.

---

How do I go to implement this in the most efficient way that I can apply to a large data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously non-trivial, but there are algorithms that at least attempt to do things like this. I hasten to add, however, that they're statistical, so trying to use only two sentences as a basis is going to be *extremely* iffy at best.

The usual approach runs something like this:

1. filter out stop words
2. use a thesaurus to substitute one canonical word for each word
3. count occurrences of words in each document/sentence
4. compute the cosine distance between the base document(s) and each candidate similar document
5. pick the N closest to the base documents

Note that there's room for a lot of variation here though. For example, the thesaurus can get considerably better results if it's context sensitive, and to maintain the context you often want to retain the stop words, at least until that step is complete. For example, consider your base documents about the weather being compared to: "I have a cold", and "It is cold". If you follow the steps above, these will both be just "cold" by step 2, and both seem equally close to the base documents.

With a context-sensitive thesaurus step (an ontology, really), you'd use the extra words to disambiguate the two uses of "cold", so when you compute distances, one would refer to the disease named "the cold", and the other to "cold weather". The base documents would both refer to cold weather, so your result would show "It is cold" as similar, but "I have a cold" as different.

If you're trying to keep things simpler, however, you might skip the thesaurus completely, and just stem the words instead. This turns "rainy" and "raining" both into "rain", so when you do comparisons they'll all show up as synonymous.

As far as details go, there are quite a few [lists](http://www.webconfs.com/stop-words.php) of [stop-words](http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html) [easily](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a11-smart-stop-list/english.stop) [found](http://search.rdsinc.com/help/stopword_list.html). At least in my testing, the choice isn't particularly critical.

For a thesaurus, I've used the [Moby Thesaurus](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3202), with some (substantial) processing to basically invert it -- i.e., rather than finding multiple synonyms for one word, find one canonical word for a given input.

There aren't as many [papers](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ai-lab/pub-view.php?PubID=126949) on context-sensitive synonym/definition searching -- but [some](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ai-lab/pub-view.php?PubID=51464) are still quite good. A lot of work on the "semantic web" and related ontologies is along this line as well (though little of it is likely to be of much help in your case).

For stemming, the [Porter Stemmer](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/index.html) is well known. There's a newer, slightly modified version (Porter2) that should be covered somewhere on the same page(s). Another well-known  algorithm is the [Lancaster Stemmer](http://www.comp.lancs.ac.uk/computing/research/stemming/). There's also the Lovins stemmer, but I wouldn't really recommend it<sup>1</sup> -- though it's still widely known because it was the first (well known) stemming algorithm published. Note that most (all?) of these strip only suffixes, not prefixes.

Quite a few [papers](http://www.miislita.com/information-retrieval-tutorial/cosine-similarity-tutorial.html) discuss cosine distance. It's well enough known that even the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) for it is pretty decent.

Quite a few people have already assembled these pieces together into coherent (at least they generally try to be coherent) tool-kits, complete programs, etc. A few reasonably well known examples include [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/), [Apache OpenNLP](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/), and [Freeling](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/).

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, Lovins only ever removes *one* suffix from a word. If you had, for example, "Loverly" and "lovingly", Porter would reduce both to "lov" and they'd show up as synonyms, but Lovins would reduce them to "lover" and "loving", respectively, and they'd show up as different. It is possible to repeat the Lovins algorithm until it removes no more suffixes, but the result isn't very good -- Porter has quite a bit of context sensitivity so (for example) it only removes one suffix if it did *not* remove another; multiple applications of Lovins wouldn't take this into account.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. For the cosine distance function, do I just need to make two vectors where I use 1 if a word exists and 0 if it does not exist? An implementation I could see is to sort both strings by lexical order and then add a 1 if it exists and a 0 if it does not exist. Or can I somehow base myself on existing pairs of which it knows they are already duplicate? Or would that be too inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

The paper [Pairwise data clustering by deterministic annealing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=566806) seems to cover exactly what you need: you have a pairwise similarity measure and you want to form a certain number of groups based on this measure. (I managed to find some free full-text pre-prints of this article a while back, so you might not need to pay to access that one; unfortunately I don't have time to hunt for them again now).

I've used this technique in [signal processing (see p15)](http://www.heeris.id.au/sites/default/files/Jason%20Heeris%20-%20Eng%20FYP.pdf), but not text-based data mining, so I'm not sure how much I'll be able to help with the specifics.

Comment: +1 Found the PDFs but I found them to include too much mathematical information and statistics (based on pictures rather than text) that kind of sets me back, it's nice to know it's called that way though.

Comment: @TomWij - I wasn't sure how "academic" you wanted it, but I figured I'd throw it in anyway :) It took me a good couple of weeks to wrap my head around that and implement something in Matlab, if that's any guide.

Answer (score 0):

It seems overambitious.  This is nearly equivalent to understanding a sentence.

I can't even quite think of a way to parametrize a sentence; you probably don't want to just input two strings of characters in your classifier.  You would need a very complex model to describe your problem and therefore a huge data set.  Your model would need to learn which words are synonyms/antonyms... among many many things it would need to learn.

Comment: Well, the sentence would be parametrized by their words. The last two sentences I gave can as well be seen as `weather really cold raining` and `weather really cold today` removing the stop words. My first idea was to implement [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or something similar that's word based, the problem is that it doesn't work well on the huge data set I have; it doesn't necessarily need to know synonyms/antonyms (I could write an apart system to replace synonyms for that matter), it is intended to *suggest* the most relevant.

Comment: In the example you give, how close the meanings of the words are is very important.  Or the correlation (cold/rainy) even if they are not synonymous.

Comment: @TomWij: My answer is clear: try another more realistic problem. I'm trying to help. (I wanted to just write a comment, but thought my answer too long.)

Comment: I did not specify that. It needs to base itself on word occurrence in sentences. The correlation between cold/rainy is unnecessary here, that is another problem which is irrelevant here and could again be solved by replacing the word. Of course something that would actually understand a sentence would work much better, but that's not what I'm aiming for. Word occurrence is fine enough for the problem I have...

Comment: The problem is realistic, it's not really hard to figure out that `weather really cold raining` shares three words with `weather really cold today` and `good music radio station` shared none. Again, I don't care about the actual meaning or interpretation of the sentence, if it were negated it would still be a duplicate because it is about the same topic. Sorry that my example was not clear enough, I should have mentioned "word occurrence" as that is what makes "I see the sunshine outside" the least relevant.

Comment: OK, that's realistic.

Comment: Glad that you see it, sometimes there are those beneficial details we don't come up with at first... :(